# Реализация сложных углов рамки

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать подобную рамку? Интересует именно форма углов, это можно сделать сделать на чистом CSS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103180/discussion-on-question-by-octavian----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы это отображалось правильно, необходимы одинаковые размеры блока и изображения.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/400);
  background-position: center center;
}

div::before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 15%, 20% 15%, 20% 0, 80% 0, 80% 15%, 100% 15%, 100% 85%, 80% 85%, 80% 100%, 20% 100%, 20% 85%, 0 85%);
}

div::after {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 10% / 13%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: с фотографией не канает...

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, большое спасибо за пример, буду разбираться)

Answer (score 2):

Либо в Photoshop делаем маску (обводим границы и заливаем нужным фоном, а внутри - полностью прозрачно чтобы было), далее ставим div с background-этой маской поверх div с изображением, либо вот такой костыль на чистом html+css, но будут присутствовать швы.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 270px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
  background: url('https://cdn.steemitimages.com/DQmPgK575YnZP6uWG3iDMqPicEqrrwgVgSGTPmo1SqSpxS8/3402463-KNVHBTVS-7.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  background: gray;
  border: 0px solid orange;
}

.one {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 60px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

.two {
  width: 221px;
  height: 80%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: -190px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}

.three {
  position: absolute;
  width: 193px;
  height: 93%;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: on two - имеют z-index , это же не работает ....мммм ?